# Minimun supported JAVA version with kafka-client 3.4.0

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka-test

We are trying to upgarde kafka-client from 2.8.2 to 3.4.0 with JAVA 11.
But while building the application its failing.

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.543 sec <<< FAILURE!
testConfigurationNotificationForCMD(com.amadeus.hotel.cde.test.rs.ConfigurationNotificationResourceIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/common/KafkaException
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:604)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
```

Can someone help me what are the things required to upgarde kafka-client to 3.4.0

Comment: Looks like you do not have the kafka libs in your classpath

Answer (score 2):

Something is odd here. The test is apparently trying to load a class called `kafka.common.KafkaException`. But according to the javadocs, the real class name is `org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException`.

So then I look at the source code for the class where this is occurring.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/test/EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java

... specifically the commit with the title: "kafka-clients 3.3.2 Compatibility".  It looks like the test code prior to this commit was using `kafka.common.KafkaException` !!!

So ... I reckon that you need to update SpringKafka to v3.0.2 or later.

See also the [release note](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/releases/tag/v3.0.2) for the SpringKafka v3.0.2 release, and [this pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2540).  And [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/f079f6159d9d6e0f5bcba60051f8f57bef79cc4d) too.

---

> Minimum supported JAVA version with kafka-client 3.4.0

The Java version is not the problem.  This is a regression in SpringKafka apparently caused by changes in the Kafka client.  You just need to use a version of SpringKafka with the fix for the regression.